# Why does my print job sometimes contain a form feed character and other times just insert more lines?

Tags: printer, network-printer

I am having an issue and I am just wracking my brain. We have a report being sent out of a program that as far as I can tell has a form feed character in the output. When this report is printed, it will either go through a local printer on the computer, or a shared printer on a server - Either way it goes, the printout seems to be inconsistent and will sometimes have extra lines instead of the form feed character.

Whether the printer is setup locally or via shared, both of these printers are pointing to the same server. This server takes the printout, saves it as a file and runs it against a bunch of criteria to take action on it. The issue is, it seems like sometimes the Form Feed Character is converted into extra lines, and sometimes it is just output as a symbol.

Both printers are pointing (using local ports) to a printer on the vendors server and are just using the Generic / Text driver. Whether setup locally or on the server, they are setup the same. Most of the time the output will contain the form feed character, occasionally it will output the extra lines instead. When it prints extra lines, the data fields expected do not match up making the process fail. I have found that removing the printer port and re-adding it will fix the issue temporarily, but we continue to see this issue.

Here is what the Form Feed Character looks like in Notepad:

[image: Form Feed]

For example, I have a computer that used to work fine. Then it randomly stopped working. When I capture the printout this is what I see when it is open in notepad:

[image: Before - Broken]

I then reinstalled the printer by removing the port and printer completely, then re added the port, then the printer, no other change and this is the printout immediately after (fixed):

[image: After - Fixed]

It seems like after it switches to the lines instead of form feed character that we need to reinstall the printer before it will start working again.

Comment: How do you know that the problem is with the print system and not the application sending the information?

Comment: Well, I guess I don't know 100%. Is there a way I can test this? I just know reinstalling the printer fixes it and assumed it was an issue with the printer side of it. Next time I see this issue, I will try to print preview and see if I can see anything there.

Comment: Change the printer port to a file name and disable print spooling to check.